# Gradle: maven-publish with dependency version range

Tags: java, maven, gradle, pom.xml, dependency-management

I'm developing a [test utilities lib](https://github.com/lovef/kotlin-assert-utils) with dependency on `kotlin-stdlib`. To have minimal impact on a project implementing my lib I tried to use a version range in the published maven pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
  <version>[1.1.2,2.0)</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN402)

> When Maven encounters multiple matches for a version reference, it uses the highest matching version

the version range should allow gradle to select a version to suit all dependencies. When testing it, however, gradle selects the highest verion available for my range, even though my test project specifies `kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2`.

```
$ ./gradlew example:dependencies
...
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:[1.1.2] -> 1.1.4-3
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
\--- se.lovef:kotlin-assert-utils:0.0-SNAPSHOT
    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:[1.1.2,2.0) -> 1.1.4-3 (*)
```

Doesn't seem to matter if I use a [hard requirement](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution#DependencyMediationandConflictResolution-DependencyVersionRanges) `[1.1.2]` or soft requirement `1.1.2`.

If I use my lib in an android project it fails:

> Resolved versions for app (1.1.3-2) and test app (1.1.4-3) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

A suggested solution is to add a resolution rule in the implementing project, eg

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

I however do not want to impose that on the users, instead I want my lib to

- use what ever version is available in the project provided that it matches my defined range `[1.1.2,2.0)`
- use the highest version matching my range if the project don't use `kotlin-stdlib`
- fail if the project dependency version don't match my lib

Is there anything I can do to my lib achieve this?

Comment: I would suggest not to use version ranges in the distributed pom file. Only use fixed versions like `1.1.2`. If a user needs he can decide to use a different one and overwrite it in Maven pom or via Gradle. But using versions ranges make each built unpredictable..which I can't recommend.

Comment: @khmarbaise my goal is is to let an implementing project define what version to use without extra code like `resolutionStrategy`, thereby making it predictable. If gradle would honor a well defined version range then I could make travis verify functionality on that range, thereby making my lib predictable. Using fixed or version range doesn't seem to make any difference, gradle may still select another version